# Set spinner selected item text

Tags: android, android-spinner, settext, onitemselectedlistener

I have a spinner (only relevant parts of code)...

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   Spinner to_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.to_spinner);
   List<Unit> list = myDbHelper.getAllUnits();
   SpinnerUnitAdapter tUnitAdapter tUnitAdapter = new SpinnerUnitAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);

   to_spinner.setAdapter(tUnitAdapter);
   to_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(onItemSelectedListenerTo);
}
```

with an onItemSelectedListener

```
AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener onItemSelectedListenerTo = new     AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
                               int position, long id) {

        // do stuff
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter) {
    }
};
```

When an item is selected (i.e. where it says: "do stuff"), I would like to set/change the text of the selected spinner item. (Note that this is *not the same* as setting the spinner position (with setSelection()).

I was thinking of doing this with

```
tUnitAdapter.getView(position, ?, ?).setText("new text");
```

Am I on the right track? What to put as second ("convertView") and third ("parent") argument in getView. My spinner adapter looks like:

```
public class SpinnerUnitAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Unit> {
     ...
     @Override
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         TextView label = new TextView(mContext);
         label.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);                        
       label.setTextSize(mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.list_row_font_size));
         label.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
         label.setText(getItem(position).getName());

         return label;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I on the right track?

No. You should do the following steps: (in the `onItemSelected` method)

- Update your model (the array of items you passed to the adapter) so that the item at `position` index takes the new name.
- Issue `notifyDataSetChanged` on the adapter object. Alternatively, you can do this manually by `((TextView) view).setText(new_name);`

**Note:** In `onItemSelected` method, `adapterView` points to your spinner view and `view` points to the row view just selected.

---

**UPDATE #1**

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
    ((TextView) view).setText("new name");
}
```

---

**UPDATE #2**

For this, you should use Java interface to implement a callback which is called once the dialog is closed.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, final View view, int position, long id) {
    Dialog dialog = new MyDialog(context, new MyDialog.OnItemSelectListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(String newName){
            ((TextView) view).setText(newName);
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}
```

And declare interface `OnItemSelectListener` in your `MyDialog` class.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't really want to change the underlying data, since they are of a different type. From a user experience what I am trying to implement is a spinner with submenus/dialog, i.e. a user selects a spinner item (say "car"), which opens up a dialog with a multiple-choice (say "Mercedes", "Porsche"...). After the user selects an item in the dialog/submenu (e.g. "VW"), the dialog/submenu will close and in the spinner it should say "VW" (not "car").

Comment: @user1583209 Okay. this is simple. Just see my edit.

Comment: That's even simpler than my solution below. Thanks. Now I just need to move this setText somehow into my dialog, so that it is executed only after a dialog item is selected. Should I pass the "view" somehow (how?)?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the text of spinner when you click each item so you should implement onClickListener

```
public class SpinnerUnitAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Unit> {
         ...
         @Override
         public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
             TextView label = new TextView(mContext);
             ...
             label.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                  // change label text here
                  // label.setText(...);
                }
             });
             return label;
        }
    }
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution. I can just do:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
                               int position, long id) {
    TextView tv = (TextView) adapterView.getSelectedView();
    tv.setText("new text");
}
```